# How to count the number of characters before a substring?

Tags: c#

I have a program that will **ask the user for a string**. Then, **ask for a substring**. I want the program then to **count the number of characters before that substring occurs for the first time**. I'm not too sure how to do this. All that comes up on Google is count before a specified character.

Comment: string.IndexOf?

Comment: Can you find the "index" where that substring is? What does that index signify?

Comment: `All that comes up on Google is count before a specified character` - you realize that "count the number of characters before that substring occurs" is the same as "count the number of characters before the first character of that substring"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, you mean the index of your string?

```
myString.IndexOf("mySearchString");
```

Comment: It's worth clarifying that with zero-based indexing (which c# uses), the *index* of the substring is equal to the number of characters before it.